# Regarding initialization of class instances

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm not sure how I would go about declaring the `timer1` instance of my subclass `Timer`. I'm told I need to initialize the instance but how do I do that if `timer1` is a class instance and not a primitive? Here's my code:

```
package com.example.derpphone;



import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public class Timer extends TimerTask {


DatagramSocket socket;

public Timer() throws SocketException { 
    this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
}

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        while (true){
                if (socket != null) {
                                   byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
                    SocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress("131.179.176.74", 9998);
                    try {
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes,
                                bytes.length, serverAddress);
                        socket.send(packet);                    

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }
}
}
    Timer timer1;
 public MainActivity () throws SocketException{
 timer1 = new Timer();
   }

String error = "error";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    View callButton = findViewById(R.id.btnCall);

    callButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    ;
}



private void phoneCall()
{
   String phoneCallUri = "tel://myPhoneNumber";
   Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
   startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
 }
 @Override 
 public void onClick(View view) {
      switch(view.getId())
      {
       case R.id.btnCall:
           timer1.run();
           phoneCall();
        break;

       case R.id.end:
           timer1.cancel();
           break;

       default:
           System.out.println(error);
        break;
      }
      }
}
```

Comment: If timer1 is not a variable, then what else can it be?

Comment: It's an instance of a sub class.

Comment: I've been told that adding the subclass is the best way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the object `Timer` isn't 1) Abstract or 2) An enum, you should use `Timer timer1 = new Timer();`

Answer (score 0):

> Timer timer1 = new Timer();

If you want to create an instance outside the MainActivity class then use:

> MainActivity.Timer timer1 = MainActivity.Timer();